# Not able post data from useState to Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to post the input data from useState to Mysql but its just not happening. While I am able to get the data from the database to the page but when it comes to posting I don't know how to send data from state hooks to mysql when there are many values. **Please take a look**

---

Code from where i am sending the form data

```
import React,{useState , useRef} from "react";
import "./AddProjects.css"
import axios from "axios";
import Projects from "../Projects/Projects";
import {BiChevronLeftCircle,BiChevronRightCircle} from "react-icons/bi"

export default function AddProjects() {
    
    
    const [AddProjects,setAddProjects] = useState({
        ProjectName:"",
        Discription:"",
        git:"",
        Img:""
    })


    const [getQuery,setGetQuery] = useState({
        projectList:[]
    })


    const inputFile = useRef(null)


    function handleChange(e) {
        const {name , value} = e.target;
        setAddProjects(newProjects => ({
            ...newProjects,[name]:value
        }))


    }
    function imgChange(e) {
        setAddProjects({ ...AddProjects, Img: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]) });
    }


    function getProjectList() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3060/projects`)
        .then((response) => response.data)
        .then(response2 => {
            setGetQuery({projectList : response2})
        })
    }

    function onSubmitHandler(e) {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3060/addProjects`,{
                ProjectName: AddProjects.ProjectName,        
                Discription:AddProjects.Discription,
                git:AddProjects.git,
                Img:AddProjects.Img
        })
        getProjectList()
    }
    return(
        <>
            <div className="AddProjects">  
                <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler} method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" >
                    <h2>Add New Project</h2>
                    <input  type="text" placeholder="Project Name..."     name="ProjectName" onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <input  type="text"   placeholder="Project Discription..."   name="Discription" onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <input  type="text"   placeholder="Git Repository/Code..."    name="git" onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <input type="file"  accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg" name="Img" onChange={imgChange} ref={inputFile} />
                    <button type="button"onClick={() => inputFile.current.click()}>Add New Image</button>
                    <button type="submit" >Submit Project</button>
                </form>
                <button onClick={getProjectList}>click me </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div className="Section-Projects" >
                <h1>My Projects </h1>
                {/* <Link to={checkBox?'/AddProjects':""} ><button className="Add-newProject" onClick={onStateChange}><IoIosAddCircleOutline/></button></Link>  */}

                <div className="Projects">
                    <button className="arrowLeft"><BiChevronLeftCircle /></button>
                            <div className="Single">
                                {getQuery.projectList.map((gettingQuery) => 
                                    <Projects   
                                    ProjectId={gettingQuery.ProjectId}
                                    ProjectName={gettingQuery.ProjectName}
                                    Discription={gettingQuery.Discription}
                                    git={gettingQuery.git}
                                    Img={gettingQuery.Img}
                                        />
                                )}
                            </div>
                        <button className="arrowRight"><BiChevronRightCircle /></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                </> 
    )

};
```

As you can see i want to send 4 things to the mysql table but i don't think the this is the way to do it and i just can't figure it out

---

Code for my file that is sending data

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const PORT = 3060;
const db  = require('./Database')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { response } = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/projects', (req,res) => {
    const TASK_QUERY = `SELECT * FROM  addprojects.newproject`;
    db.query(TASK_QUERY , (err, response) => {
        if(err) res.status(404).send('somthings wrong')
        else res.send(response)
    })
});

app.post('/addProjects', (req,res) => {
    const ADD_QUERY = `INSERT INTO addprojects.newproject VALUES('${req.body.data}')`;
    db.query(ADD_QUERY, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else res.send('Query added sucsessfully')
    })
    
} );

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('app is listning to port 3000')
})
```

I think while the post method is correct the Value is not so please help I am on this for 2 days **Any suggestion will be help full**

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (columnName1, columnName2) VALUES ('Company Inc', 'Highway 37')
```

For backend:

You don't mention the columns name, it doesn't know which field belongs to which column in the table.

For Frontend:

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:3060/addProjects`,{
            ProjectName: AddProjects.ProjectName,        
            Discription:AddProjects.Discription,
            git:AddProjects.git,
            Img:AddProjects.Img
    })
```

ProjectName,Discription,git,Img make these keys name exact to your column names.
And you are uploading an image in this api so convert your data from front in formdata then pass that data in api and on backend you will that data in formdata

Comment: What should i put in After Values ? in backend

Comment: const ADD_QUERY = `INSERT INTO addprojects.newproject (colName1,colName2) VALUES('${req.body.data}')`;
add column names from your table in which you want to insert data

Comment: Still no working even after changing the values